# return NULL; vs. return;

Tags: php

I wonder if there are any differences in `PHP`.
Lets assume I have the following function(s)

```
public function myFunc() {
    // some logic here
    return;
}
```

and this here:

```
public function myFunc2() {
     // some more logic here
     return null;
}
```

I understand, that returning `""` (an empty String) is something different than `null`. A var_dump() on each of these functions returns NULL. Is this internally (bitwise or for some comparison) somehow handled differently?

Does it affect the parsing-time? Is it just a good practice to write `return NULL` or is it more like a convention?

Comment: I don't think there's any difference at all except syntactically/semantically. I'd say `return;` is more semantically meaningful for a function that really truly never returns any data. Like for example `printOutTheWebsite()` could break early with a `return;` since it mostlikey has no meaningful data to return. A function that should return data, like `getDatabaseConnection` could meaningfully `return null;`. Just my opinoin

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't studied source code of PHP, but as a developer I'm using `return null` when function should return a value (by design) and simple `return` when I need to just leave a function which is not returning any value.

Comment: So, in case of void-methods (which are supported since php 7) you would just write "return"? I'll update the question real quick to include PHP 7

Comment: Don't know PHP 7 exactly, but if it works same as eg. C# void method I'll write just `return`, yes.

Comment: Is null a value in PHP?

Comment: I'm convinced that null is a special type of value. If variable isn't defined and you read its value you get null, but you'll also get null once the variable is defined and doesnt have a value.